# Как посмотреть откуда подгружаются мои изображения на мой сайт?

Tags: php, html, кэширование

Такая ситуация. У меня на сайте подгружаются изображения. Сами изображения сохраняются в папке сайта, в базе прописывается путь к этим изображениям. Загружаю сайт и по этому пути в базе у меня выходит изображение (например выгрузка карточки сотрудника с фото). Теперь я стираю это фото по указанному пути. Перегружаю комп. Включаю сайт. Делаю аналогичные запросы на другие изображения (открываю другие карточки сотрудников). Возвращаюсь к карточке с удаленным фото и (о, чудо) на карточке по-прежнему отображается удаленное фото. Откуда оно берется? Да, сразу если это остается где-то в кэши научите как это подчистить.

Comment: Обычно ctrl-f5 помогает

Answer (score 1):

Либо кэш в браузере, тогда через ctrl - f5 сбросить можно. Либо очистить кэш состояний файла на сервере с помощью `clearstatcache();`, но это в случае если вы используете функции `stat(), lstat(), file_exists(), is_writable(), is_readable(), is_executable(), is_file(), is_dir(), is_link(), filectime(), fileatime(), filemtime(), fileinode(), filegroup(), fileowner(), filesize(), filetype(), fileperms().`. А вообще на время разработки лучше отключить кэширование. Просто добавьте в заголовок `header('Pragma: no-cache');` и для отключения кэширования на сервере отключите расширение `opcache`

Comment: Ctrl+F5 не помогает, перегрузка не помогает. Прочитал и сделал: очистка истории браузера решила вопрос, но это как-то не правильно. Возился с параметрами изображения в php поэтому думал что clearstatcache() помогла. Но вот опять упирается продолжает загружать давно стертое изображение. Может не там где надо устанавливаю clearstatcache() ?